# Unable to iterate over list

Tags: java

I'm appending to a list then throwing that list into a function below:

```
 List<ItemBean> itemList;

        for (Object bean : beans)
        {
            if (!bean.getItem().isActive())
            {
                itemList.add(bean.getItem().getId());
            }
       }

       if (!itemList.isEmpty())
       {
        // Source of Supply List
        buildItemList( request, commonDAO, false );
       }
       else{
           buildItemFilterList( request, commonDAO, itemList);

       }
```

But I'm getting "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" error here:

```
 protected final List<ItemBean> buildItemFilterList( HttpServletRequest request,
                                                             CommonDAO dao,
                                                             ItemBean list
                                                            )
    throws Exception
{
    List<ItemBean> itemList = dao.getAllItems( false );
    ItemBean item;

    for (ItemBean s: list )  <<<<<-----ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        item = dao.getItemById(s.getId());
        itemList.add(item);
    }

    Collections.sort( itemList );
    request.setAttribute("itemList", itemList);
    return itemList;
}
```

Comment: *WHAT* error? Also, `throws Exception` is not very sensible.

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is, that your argument "SourceOfSupplyBean list" is not a collection.

```
protected final List<ItemBean> buildItemFilterList( 
     HttpServletRequest request,
     CommonDAO dao,
     List<ItemBean> list
)
```

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, parameter 'list' is of type of `ItemBean` and `ItemBean` is not an instance of `Iterable` or an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected final List<ItemBean> buildItemFilterList( HttpServletRequest request,
                                                             CommonDAO dao,
                                                             ItemBean list
                                                            )
    throws Exception
{
    List<ItemBean> itemList = dao.getAllItems( false );
    ItemBean item;

    for (ItemBean s: list )  <<<<<-----ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        item = dao.getItemById(s.getId());
        itemList.add(item); <<< --real error is here.
    }

    Collections.sort( itemList );
    request.setAttribute("itemList", itemList);
    return itemList;
}
```

You cannot modify a list while iterating through it.

Comment: list <> sosList, that access is legit :)

Comment: Sorry! I thought it was a typo in the variable name :(